# WiFi connection very unstable even with different APs, tried everything

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

My WiFi connection at home has been very unreliably since a few months. Some devices (a Lenovo Thinkpad T460p, a Raspberry Pi Zero W and a Nintendo WiiU) work just fine, while others (multiple Samsung Galaxy S3, a Motorola Moto M, an USB WiFi device on another Raspberry and some more) continuously disconnect.

Watching any kind of video stream is basically impossible on these devices - I can connect to my Network, and sometimes even stay connected for a minute or two, but as soon as I try to "do" something, so, when the WiFi is actively used, it crashes. On Android, the WiFi icon in the status bar disappears, indicating the connection has been lost. Checking "dmesg" in the terminal doesn't show anything suspicious (just a normal disconnect. I'll append the dmesg log later if needed). After about 5-10 seconds, it reconnects. If I'm not actively transmitting data, the connection usually stays for multiple minutes. The more I "use" it, the higher the probability that it crashes immediately. Like, watching Twitch or YouTube is impossible (immediate disconnect), but opening just one web page or checking for new mails usually works without disconnect.

I have tried:

- Operating the affected devices in my University's WiFi. They work just fine there.
- Reset my WiFi AP to its factory defaults.
- Reset one of the Android devices to its factory defaults.
- Change WiFi channels.
- Tried different distances between AP and device, including directly next to it (100 % signal), in the next room (~90 % signal) or one floor above (~50 % signal)
- Trying multiple different WiFi routers at my home, including:

  - an old Linksys-something with dd-wrt
  - an old Netgear WiFi AP
  - an AVM FRITZ!Box 7270v2
  - an AVM FRITZ!Box 6360
  - an Ubiquiti Unifi AP AC Pro

(none of which have solved the problem)

No device or AP shows / showed anything useful in any log - they just lose connection, and, depending on how they are configured, try to connect again or not.

It is very damn annoying having to connect every Raspberry, every Laptop, every device using a LAN cable if I want to have a connection for more than about 5 seconds.

What the heck could be wrong with my WiFi or my devices or whatever and how could I fix it? It appears with different clients, so it isn't one client being broken / misbehaving / whatever, and it appears with multiple different APs, with all the others turned off (so, no AP mess with multiple of them running, I tested only one AP at a time), so this isn't an issue with the AP. And I even tried 5GHz and / or other channels, so I doubt this is caused by another WiFi network.

I really don't have any other idea but I hope someone else does.

EDIT: About the questions in the comments:

- I have checked the Fritzbox log ("Ereignisse" -> "WLAN" with enabled "An- und Abmeldungen dokumentieren, in English "Events" -> "WiFi" including "Log WiFi connections and disconnections) and the Unifi log (by clicking the "Events" button in the bottom left where it says things like " connected to  with ssid  on channel ", but these short reconnections do not show up there - only the very first entry for the first connection after enabling WiFi. The Unifi controller doesn't even reset the device update displayed in the devices tab. As if it wouldn't even recognize the device reconnecting... Does any of these devices have a more advanced log?

This is the output of "dmesg" on an Android device when the disconnect happens:

```
c0 CFG80211-INFO2) wl_cfg80211_disconnect : Reason 3
c0 CFG80211-INFO2) wl_is_linkdown : Link down Reason : WLC_E_LINK
c0 link down if wlan0 may call cfg80211_disconnected. event : 16, reason=2 from 78:d6:f2
c0 cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
c0 CFG80211-TRACE) wl_cfg80211_set_btcoex_dhcp : DHCP is complete
c0 CFG80211-TRACE) wl_cfg80211_set_btcoex_dhcp : DHCP is complete
c0 CFG80211-TRACE) __wl_cfg80211_scan : START SCAN
```

And then it starts reconnecting (the 78:d6:f2 in the log is part of my APs MAC address - 78:xx:xx:xx:d6:f2)

I also found some more logging on the AP itself:

```
Jan  3 19:11:30 UBNT daemon.info hostapd: ath0: STA f0:xx:xx:xx:xx:20 IEEE 802.11: sta_stats
Jan  3 19:11:30 UBNT daemon.info hostapd: ath0: STA f0:xx:xx:xx:xx:20 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Jan  3 19:11:30 UBNT user.info libubnt[4134]: wevent.ubnt_custom_event(): EVENT_STA_LEAVE ath0: f0:xx:xx:xx:xx:20 / 5
```

f0:xx:xx:xx:xx:20 is the phone I currently had connected which again randomly disconnected.

Comment: I had same problem and somehow figured out that It was `Power Management` that If anytime signal level dropped, It just disconnected my laptop. Very frustrating Sometimes. Then I disabled the Power Management using this command **`iwconfig wlp6s0 power off`**. It worked but sometimes I just have to `restart NetworkManager` again

Comment: "No device or AP shows / showed anything useful in any log" simply isn't true. An AP AC Pro throws out plenty of logs - so does the fritzbox,ddwrt but not the netgear. You need to setup logging and a computer to receive the logs before any other help can be given.

Comment: Something isn’t adding up. You can’t use different bands, on different channels, on different APs, on different devices, at different ranges, and still have problems unless something unrelated is going on. This is one of two things - interference or a deliberate attack by a nearby neighbor. If you’re in any moderately populous area, especially near an apartment or dense housing area this is really not surprising. The only way to solve this problem will be with a spectrum and protocol analyzer.

Comment: New information: The issue somehow seems to be related to Multicast / Broadcast traffic. If I enable the "Block LAN to WLAN Multicast and Broadcast Data" setting in my AP, the issues disappear and my devices stay connected. However, blocking Multicast breaks IPv6 SLAAC in the network ...